# Methods not completing before the next one is executed (javascript jquery google maps v3 api)

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous

I have been trying to place multiple map markers from lat lng coords in an xml file.

this is my code

```
    var stockistName=[];
        var stockistAddress=[];
        var stockistLat=[];
        var stockistLng=[];


    function getAddresses(country){

         $.get('xml/stockists/'+country+'.xml', function(d){
                      alert("file Opened");
         $(d).find('stockist').each(function(){
            $stockist = $(this);
            stockistName.push($stockist.attr("name"));      
            stockistAddress.push($stockist.attr("address"));
            stockistLat.push($stockist.attr("lat"));
            stockistLng.push($stockist.attr("lng"));
            });
        });
    placeMarkerArray();
}
function placeMarkerArray(){

        alert("this is element 0"+stockistName[0]);
        for(var i=0; i<stockistName.length;i++){
            alert("in the function got addresses");
        //alert("inloop"+i+"");

        var newLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(stockistLat[i], stockistLng[i]);
        //alert("making marker lat lng:"+newLatLng+"")
            if (markerArray[i] != undefined){
                markerArray[i].setPosition(newLatLng); 
            }
            else{
                markerArray[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: newLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon:'images/icons/MAP/van.png'
                });
            }
        }
}`
```

I have been reading about callback functions but can't seem to grasp the idea. I always thought that things would be executed in the order you write them. If anyone could give me any direction that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think things are usually clearest with an example, so:

```
// define a function that accepts a function as a parameter and calls
// this function after one second asynchronously.
function executeActionDelayed (action) {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        action();
        }, 1000);
}

// Now call the above function with an anonymous function as the parameter.
executeActionDelayed(function () {
    console.log("Execute action delayed called.");
});

console.log("End, or is it?");
```

As you can see in this example, the "End, or is it?" was actually logged to the console before "Execute action delayed called.". This is
because `window.setTimeout` is asynchronous. The function I created `executeActionDelayed` is using a callback!

This is similar to what you're doing with jQuery's `get` function:

```
// This function is being passed in as a parameter and will be
// called only when the response has been received.
$.get('xml/stockists/'+country+'.xml', function(d){
    // stuff removed.
});
```

### So what does this mean for you?

You have to call your function that uses the data within the success callback that you pass in:

```
function getAddresses(country){
     $.get('xml/stockists/'+country+'.xml', function(d){
        alert("file Opened");
        $(d).find('stockist').each(function(){
            $stockist = $(this);
            stockistName.push($stockist.attr("name"));      
            stockistAddress.push($stockist.attr("address"));
            stockistLat.push($stockist.attr("lat"));
            stockistLng.push($stockist.attr("lng"));
        });
        placeMarkerArray();
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example but I am still confused how to implement this. Do I need to pass the placeMarkerArray through another function as its parameter and call that from inside the getAddress method ?

Comment: @JackTaylor Nope, all you need to do is move your call to `placeMarkerArray` directly after the `.each`. I updated the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Seriously I cant get this into my head, so would your code look like this  $(d).find('stockist').each(placeMarkerArray(function(){
     $stockist = $(this);
     stockistName.push($stockist.attr("name"));  
     stockistAddress.push($stockist.attr("address"));
     stockistLat.push($stockist.attr("lat"));
     stockistLng.push($stockist.attr("lng"));
    }));

Comment: @JackTaylor - I wrote the full version of what you need for `getAddresses` in the answer. Then all you need to do in your code is call that function.

Comment: so if i call get addresses it should wor k/

Comment: @JackTaylor - yes, if you copy the code from the answer above.

Comment: Ah got it working, was not working because it was in a seperate script file

Answer (score 0):

The *$.get* method needs to download a file which can take some time. This is why you give it a callback function as a second parameter, it will be called later, when the download is finished.

Meanwhile, your JS keeps executing in the order you wrote it. Which is why after the *get* call, which starts downloading the file, the *placeMarkerArray* function is executed.
You should just move the *placeMarkerArray()* call inside the *$.get* callback.

Also, you should improve your code indentation, it will make things much clearer.